# Change the posts loop design of a wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, loops

i want to change the design of the posts loop in my cross-apple wordress theme.
instead of big thumbnail at the bottom of the title and the small description, i want small thumbnail (200x200) direct to the right and the title and the small description will display next to it at the left (like in the [newscast wordpress theme](http://www.kriesi.at/themes/newscast/category/community/))

here is how my loop looks:
http://cor.co.il/info

i want the posts loop to look like this: http://www.kriesi.at/themes/newscast/category/community/

how do i manage that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change "archive.php" in your theme.

In it try to use this loop:

```
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
  *your html code for one post*
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

To display thumbnail in loop:

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

To display the title in loop:

```
the_title();
```

And to display description:

```
the_content();
```

For more informations look at this -> [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Answer (score 0):

Solve it myself!

i had to change the lines from:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('650-200'); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(array(200,200), array('class' => 'alignright')); ?>
```

see it in action: http://cor.co.il/info